# How to directly access physical addresses or convert to virtual address on macOS for Apple silicon?

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, iokit, kernel-extension

I am trying to read data using a physical address on Apple Silicon MacOS.
I think the best way is to convert the physical address to a virtual address and access it, or access it directly with the physical address.

I guess I could achieve this with IOKit (or kext).
However, I couldn't find any documentation about the API or Syscall related to this. Could I please get some advice on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend that you take [the tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven’t already done so. Another useful resource to check prior to your first question would be the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your question is incoherent. Which is to say, it doesn't make any sense. You can only read from a non-virtual, physical, address while running in the kernel or after establishing an appropriate virtual to physical mapping in a user process. If you provide more context explaining why your user process needs to read from a physical address it is likely to yield more useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

From a kext, you can use [`IOMemoryDescriptor::withPhysicalAddress()`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/xnu-10002.81.5/iokit/IOKit/IOMemoryDescriptor.h#L519) to create an `IOMemoryDescriptor`, which you can then map into any address space you want, either via `map()` for the kernel's address space, or `createMappingInTask()` for userland processes.

Example:

```cpp
IOMemoryDescriptor *desc = IOMemoryDescriptor::withPhysicalAddress((IOPhysicalAddress)0x12345678, 0x4000, kIODirectionInOut);
if(!desc)
{
    // [error handling]
}
IOMemoryMap *map = desc->map(kIOMapInhibitCache); // kIOMapInhibitCache is only needed for MMIO, for DRAM you can pass 0x0
if(!map)
{
    // [error handling]
}
void *ptr = (void*)map->getVirtualAddress();

// [access memory through ptr]

map->release();
desc->release();
```

I wrote [a kext](https://github.com/Siguza/IOKernelRW) not long ago that does exactly this, and exposes this functionality to userland via IOKit external methods, along with [some convenience wrappers](https://github.com/Siguza/IOKernelRW/blob/master/lib/iokernelrw.h).